# Javascript Calculations Producing Unexpected Results

Tags: javascript

```
<head>
    <title>Javascript Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
        function calc_form() {
            discPerc = document.forms["calc"].elements["disc_perc"].value;
            totDays = document.forms["calc"].elements["tot_days"].value;
            discPer = document.forms["calc"].elements["disc_per"].value;
            discDays = document.forms["calc"].elements["disc_days"].value;
            discCalc = Math.round([(discPerc/100)/((100-discPerc)/100)]*(totDays/(discPer-discDays)));
            document.forms["calc"].elements["result"].value = discCalc*100 + "%";
            document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = discCalc*100 + "%";
            //return Math.round(discCalc);
        }
    </script>
<form name = "calc">
    Discount Percentage:
    <br>
    <input type = "text" name="disc_perc">
    <br>
    Enter Total Days in a year:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="tot_days">
    <br>
    Enter Discount Days:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="disc_days">
    <br>
    Enter Discount Period
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="disc_per">
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick = "calc_form()">
    <br>   <br>
    Cost of forgoing discount:
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="result">
</form>
<p id="result1"></p>

</body>
```

The above code is generating unexpected results. Of course, there is a bug in it but I'm not able to understand. When I'm enclosing discCalc variable in Math.round function the output is entirely different as compared to when I'm not.

Kindly someone explain this discrepancy.

Thank you.

Comment: *"The above code is generating unexpected results."* Like what?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder:
Let's start with first input field and then move ahead from there:
I'm entering, 1, 360, 10, 30 in the respective fields.

Without Math.round, the answer is 18.181818...3% which is correct. However, as I add Math.round function in discCalc variable, the output is 0. 

Hope this helps.

Comment: For the example you provided, disCalc is 0.181818 (you convert it to % afterwards), so a Math.round(0.181818) == 0. If you want a rounded % multiply it by 100 inside the Math.round()

Comment: But when I enter 3 in the Discount Percentage field, the output becomes 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the problem by using variable.toFixed(2) instead of using Math.round() function. So the code is:

```
<script>
        function calc_form() {
            discPerc = document.forms["calc"].elements["disc_perc"].value;
            totDays = document.forms["calc"].elements["tot_days"].value;
            discPer = document.forms["calc"].elements["disc_per"].value;
            discDays = document.forms["calc"].elements["disc_days"].value;
            //discCalc = Math.round([(discPerc/100)/((100-discPerc)/100)]*(totDays/(discPer-discDays)));
            discCalc = [(discPerc)/((100-discPerc))]*(totDays/(discPer-discDays));
            discCalc_2 = discCalc*100;
            document.forms["calc"].elements["result"].value = discCalc_2.toFixed(2) + "%";
            document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = discCalc_2.toFixed(2) + "%";
            //return Math.round(discCalc);
        }
    </script>
<form name = "calc">
    Discount Percentage:
    <br>
    <input type = "text" name="disc_perc">
    <br>
    Enter Total Days in a year:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="tot_days">
    <br>
    Enter Discount Days:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="disc_days">
    <br>
    Enter Discount Period
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="disc_per">
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick = "calc_form()">
    <br>   <br>
    Cost of forgoing discount:
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="result">
</form>
<p id="result1"></p>
```